# Performance with several Web processes running

Tags: heroku

I'm in development for a Rails app and I am confused about what I'm seeing. I am new to this so I may misinterpreting the information. When I run one web process I am getting good results. But when I up the web process I am not getting the results I expect. I am trying to calculate how many I will need to run in production so I can determine my costs.

Based on New Relic I have response times of 40-60 MS per request at 3000 requests per minute (or about 50 requests per second) on one Heroku Dyno. Things are working just fine and the web processes are not even being pushed. Some responses are timing out at 1 second on Blitz, but I expect because I'm pushing as much as I can through one Dyno.

Now I try cranking up the Dyno's. First to 10 then to 50. I rush with Blitz again and get the same results as above. With 50 dynos running I blitz the website with 250 concurrent users and I get response times of 2 or 3 seconds. New Relic is reading the same traffic as one dyno, 3000 requests per second with 60MS request times. Blitz is seeing 3 second response times and getting a max of 50 to 60 rps.

In the logs I can see the activity split nicely between the different web processes. I am just testing against the home page and not accessing any external services or database calls. I'm not using caching.

I don't understand why a single web process easily handle up to 60 requests per second (per Blitz), but when increasing to 10 or even 50 web processes I don't get any additional performance. I did the Blitz rushes several times ramping up concurrent users.

Anyone have any ideas about what's happening?

Comment: Is there a database or key-value store involved in the application?

Comment: There is a database that is not accessed by the pages tested.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up removing the app server, Unicorn, from my app and adding it back in again. Now I'm getting 225 hits per sec with 250 concurrent users on one dyno. Running multiple Dyno's seems to work just fine as well. Must have been an error in setting up the App Server. Never did track down the exact error though.